# register functions with additional arguments?

Tags: python, vaex

Is there a way to define a function with additional arguments?

My function currently works in the following way:

```
@vaex.register_function()
def abc(field)  :
        o = len( set(txt.str.split(' ')) )
        return o

df.func.field.abc()
```

I want it to work roughly like this:

```
@vaex.register_function()
def abc(field, arg2)    :
        o = len( set(txt.str.split(' ')) & set(arg2.split(' ')) )
        return o

df.func.field.abc(arg2)
```

Currently I do:

```
arg2 = '  ...  '
df.apply(lambda a: abc(a,arg2), arguments=[df.field])
```

which from what I've read is not optimized, not jitted and slow because it is applied from 'outside'

Answer (score 0):

So I believe that what you are looking for is supported. Consider the example:

```py
import vaex
import vaex.ml

df = vaex.ml.datasets.load_iris()

@vaex.register_function()  # check the arguments here for more options
def my_func(x, number1=1, number2=10):
    return x * number1 + number2

df.sepal_length.my_func(number1=1, number2=2)
```

So the above should just work.

Regarding `apply` - in vaex 4.x `apply` is executed in parallel. The code is as efficient as you make it.

Register function is more of a convenience, if you build your own module for your own work, and extending vaex with various functions that are often use by you. The performance will depend on the code written.